# Howto parse string like '/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd'?

Tags: c#, regex

Here is the sample string like '/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd' or '/aaa/zzz'
I want to get a Regex to get each block, like
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd

thus, I wrote

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(/[^/]*)*");
```

But it can only get last match,
/ddd
How can I get everyone, Many thanks.

update my question:
I know 'split'，just for fun.
the situation is I have a string:

```
string s = @"ftp://127.0.0.1/TE ST.中文 空格CC/T # ES T.OK/# ##中文 测试##^#@!aaa.txt";
```

I want to encode each block between /.../ (using Uri.EscapeDataString(each))
I prefer to use Regex.Replace, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial question, using a `Regex`:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(/[^/]*)");
var matches = r.Matches("/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd");

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    // ...  
}
```

Simply removed the trailing `*` of your pattern.

Your second question:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"/([^/]*)");
var result = r.Replace("1.1.1.1/aaa/bbb/ccc/test.ext", match => { 
    return string.Format("/{0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(match.Groups[1].Value)); 
});
```

Comment: it's ok.if i have a string like 'ftp://1.1.1.1/aaa/bbb/ccc/test.ext', i want to replace 'aaa'=>Uri.EscapeDataString('aaa') and 'bbb','ccc','test.ext' do the same, how to do that?

Answer (score 9):

You don't need (and shouldn't use) regex for something so simple.

```
string s = "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd";
var blocks = s.Split('/');
foreach(var block in blocks) {
    Console.WriteLine(block);
}
```

Output:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Edit: Oh, I see what you're trying to do. So now we don't want to remove empty entries and we want to say

```
string encoded = String.Join("/", blocks.Select(b => Uri.EscapeDataString(b)));
```

Comment: Try Regex.Replace each block by Uri.EscapeDataString(each block)

Answer (score 5):

In this case, why not just split on / ?

```
String[] split = "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd".split("/");
```

(note, it has been a while since I wrote C#, so the above might contain one or two errors, however the idea should be clear.)

Comment: String[] split = "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd".Split('/'); that's all the change needed to be done!

Answer (score 1):

thanks for everyone, i wrote them this morning.

```
string s = @"ftp://127.0.0.1/# #/中 文.NET/###_%TRY 字符.txt";

s = ftpUrlPattern.Replace(s, new MatchEvaluator((match) => {
    return "/" + Uri.EscapeDataString(match.Groups["tag"].Value);
}));
```

the pattern like this:

```
static Regex ftpUrlPattern = new Regex(@"(?<!/)/(?<tag>[^/]+)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling the *Match* method and want *Matches*. However, you could also use the split method and just split on "/" (if i understand your use correctly).

To replace:

```
public void Replace(string input)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(@"(/[^/]*)");
    var matchEval = new MatchEvaluator(Encode);
    r.Replace(input, matchEval);
}

public string Encode(Match m)
{
    //TODO: Encode the match
}
```

Note: I have not run this but the methodology should be sound.